# AWS CodePipeline doesn't work anymore - GitHub's token insufficient permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-codepipeline

I've created AWS Code Pipeline with GitHub as a source. It was working fine and I was able to fetch repository from GitHub without difficulties. I've deployed my app million times through this pipeline.

Until last Sunday (15-11-2015) when I tried to release changes to my pipeline.

Since then I'm getting

> Either the GitHub repository "epub" does not exist, or the GitHub
>   access token provided has insufficient permissions to access the
>   repository. Verify that the repository exists and edit the pipeline to
>   reconnect the action to GitHub.

error message.

I've deleted the pipeline, revoked access to all AWS services on GitHub, created the pipeline from scratch granting access to AWS CodePipeline App on GitHub.
I'm able to set up pipeline correctly, when I'm connecting to GitHub while setting up the pipeline, I'm able to fetch all the repos, and choose branch.

But then after I'm running the pipeline I'm getting this annoying error.

It seems to me that this is an GitHub - AWS access issue, but I have no control over it, as AWS CodePipeline in GitHub's authorised applications controls it.

I'm trying to figure it out for a couple of days now but without success going through different tutorials and potential solutions

Any advise?

Comment: If you go to GitHub's settings -> Applications -> AWS CodePipeline. What Permissions does AWS CodePipeline have?

Comment: Full control of repository hooks and 
 Access private repositories, and it seems impossible to change it. The only option is revoking.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing this recently as well; however, it looks like a false-negative: when I push to a branch being watched, despite the Pipeline showing that stage in error, it pulls and delivers source to the next stage.

Strange behavior, but not actually an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Due to a limitation in CodePipeline, if your GitHub account has a large number of repositories you can encounter this error (even though the permissions are set up correctly). This happens with around 2,000 repositories, including repositories where you're a collaborator or an organization member.

Thanks for making us aware of this issue. I will update this post once this limitation is removed, but unfortunately I can't give an estimate for when that will happen.

Comment: Is it the official AWS response ? Is it something that has changed recently ? The number of my repositories hasn't changed. What is the current limit ? When can it be fixed ? What priority it has for you ? For me it's a critical bug as I can't deploy my code anymore. And also, I had to pay for additional pipelines because of this issue. Thanks

Comment: I don't buy this unless it's an official AWS response. I'm getting it with only about 30 repositories across 3 orgs that I'm subscribed to