# Unable to stage source on AWS Codestar pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codestar

I was attempting to change the meta tags on my organization's angular project in the index.html. Our aws pipeline retrieves code from our github repository's master branch. Upon pushing the change, CodeStar on aws fails at the source.

We've reverted back to an older commit but still end up with the same error on CodeStar. The error on aws says:

"Invalid action configuration

Either the GitHub repository "quote-flow-v3" does not exist, or the GitHub access token provided has insufficient permissions to access the repository. Verify that the repository exists and edit the pipeline to reconnect the action to GitHub."

Normally, the code would publish to the live site upon pushing to changes. I've looked around and the closest I got to this issue is on here: 
[AWS CodePipeline doesn't work anymore - GitHub's token insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830979/aws-codepipeline-doesnt-work-anymore-githubs-token-insufficient-permissions)

However, there doesn't seem to be a solution. Recreating the pipeline is not an option. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED-

This problem occurred after a key member on our team left the git organization. Turns out the OAuth was attached to his git account. Fixed the issue be assigning the OAuth to a different admin!